# Knowing what persistent store a query comes from

Tags: core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext, nspersistentstore

It's possible what I'm trying to do can't be done with Core Data so, if so, please let me know.

I have a ManagedObjectContext and I'm bringing in sqlite databases by adding them through addPersistentStoreWithType . . .

So I'll add in some number of databases - let's say between 1 and 5 and then I perform fetches on data in the databases.  It's great that I don't have to say what sources I'm searching through - results just come back and they're merged together.

However, what if I *WANT* to know what Store each result came out of?  Is that even possible?  Am I thinking too "old school" like I want to know what "files" the results were found?

Help / advice would be appreciated.

Here's some code:

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"PMBEntity"
    inManagedObjectContext:context];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]
                                    initWithKey:@"Name" ascending:YES];
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor]];
[fetchRequest setReturnsDistinctResults:YES];
[sortDescriptor release];

NSArray *fetchedObjects = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
```

See, above I have a PMBEntity which is a Core Data NSManagedObjectModel I created through XCode.  As you can tell, one (of the many) fields is "Name".  Here I'm searching for all unique Names and sorting by Name.

What is returned to me is an NSArray of these PMBEntity objects.

Comment: [link]http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSPersistentStoreCoordinator_Class/NSPersistentStoreCoordinator.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSPersistentStoreCoordinator[/link] seems to imply that I should be able to do this - but I can't see how:

Comment: The coordinator gives access to its underlying object stores. You can retrieve an object store when you first add one (using addPersistentStoreWithType:configuration:URL:options:error:), or by using persistentStoreForURL: or persistentStores. This allows you to to determine, for example, whether a store has already been added, **or whether two objects come from the same store**.

Comment: Why do you specifically need to have multiple databases?

Comment: Because for this app users are adding their own database through iTunes.  I'd like to be able to present to them what data came from what source.

Comment: So, you are generating the NSManagedObjectModel on the fly?

Comment: The database (even those added by the user) have a very defined structure and only allow more additions to this Core Data ManagedObjectModel.  Imagine an ObjectModel for an address book (name, address, phone, email, etc) and the app ships with some and users can add their own databases which are maintained external to the app.  So there's one managedObjectModel for the entire app - with additional stores added to it.  Now given a return from a fetch, how can I look back and see what store it came from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want the `persistentStore` attribute of the managed object's `objectID` attribute. That will provide you a URL to the persistent store holding the managed object.

However, that is only after the object has been saved at least once to the persistent store. Prior to that it has a temporary UUID that doesn't point to a store. I'm not sure how it is effected by the new imported stores. Probably gets an permanent ID when read in but I haven't test it yet.

Comment: Perfect!  This is what I was looking for.  Thank you: `[[instanceOfNSManagedObject] objectID] persistentStore]` works.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Well, when when you fetch, you have NSManagedObject instances as the result. The NSManagedObject instance has a reference to its NSManagedObjectContext. That NSManagedObjectContext has a reference to its persistentStoreCoordinator. The NSPersistentStoreCoordinator instance has a reference to the persistent store and the NSManagedObjectModel.

Comment: I can see the methods to get at the persistent store but it returns an array of persistent stores that are under management, not the particular one (if you will "file" in my mind) that it pulled it from.  Can you explain further?

Comment: `NSArray *foo = [[[p managedObjectContext] persistentStoreCoordinator] persistentStores];` returns an array of all 3 persistent stores I have added - not the one that it found this object 'p' from.

Comment: You need to find the store metadata and find if the record you are getting is contained in the metadata of the persistent stores.

Comment: Can you give me a pointer to the methods?  I realize the concept of what I need to do I just can't figure out how to do it.